# Get a number between 2 words (NO SPACES IN OUTPUT)

Tags: php

I need to get a number, which is between 2 words, which is:

```
"Playing2Favorites25Visits2,206Created1/4/2019Updated4/5/2019Max Players20GenreRPGAllowed GearReport Abuse"
```

I want the first number, which is 2.

The code I am using to pull that text is:

```
error_reporting(0);


@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$link ="https://web.roblox.com/games/2710592004/Pictionary-Reborn";

//Get ROBLOX username
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($link);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='section-content remove-panel']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
$var = $entries->item(0)->textContent;
$players = $var;

echo "<p class='site'>$players</p>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex. This looks for the first digits after the start of the line and stores them in capture group 1:

```
$players = "Playing2Favorites25Visits2,206Created1/4/2019Updated4/5/2019Max Players20GenreRPGAllowed GearReport Abuse";

preg_match('/^[A-Z]+(\d+)/i', $players, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Output:

```
2
```